# Same sounds spelled more than one way

Tags: morphology, pronunciation, orthography

Why are there multiple ways for expressing the same sound?

 In English, for example, you can say "axe" or "aks," or when "c" sounds like "s" like in "face."

This phenomenon exists in many different languages. Is it just the evolution of pronunciation of certain letters that once had different sounds?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a very common phenomenon, where a sound in a language can be spelled in multiple ways, or a certain spelling can have multiple pronunciations.

To give a quick answer to your question: **Written and spoken forms of a language can change independently.**

Let's start by looking at the two cases you mention: |x| and |c|, and we'll also look at silent |k|.  We'll follow the convention of putting spellings between |vertical pipes| and putting pronunciations between /slashes/.

### |x| might as well be |ks|

Why do we have |x| at all?  Historical accident -- the letter |x| was used to spell /ks/ in Western Greek, then was borrowed by the Etruscans, then by the Romans, then by the Saxons.  Usually when people borrow a writing system, they borrow the whole thing, even if it's not a perfect fit for their own language.

### |c| says either /k/ or /s/

Two questions come up here: Why does |c| have two sounds?  Why do we have |c| in the first place?

- Greek had a letter |Γ| for /g/ and a letter |Κ| for /k/.  The Etruscans didn't distinguish these sounds in their language, so they only needed one of the two.  They kept |Γ| and gradually dropped |Κ|.  The Romans borrowed the Etruscan alphabet, but their language *did* distinguish /g/ and /k/, so they made a variant form of |Γ| by adding a little tail to it, thus distinguishing |C| from |G|.
- A sound change occurred in some parts of the Latin-speaking world where /k/ changed to /s/ in certain environments.  The sounds changed, but the spelling didn't.  So where |cena| used to be pronounced /kena/, it ended up being pronounced /sena/.

## silent |k|

This one doesn't come from Latin at all.  In Old English, the word "knight" was pronounced /kniht/ -- both the |k| and the |gh| were pronounced.  Over the centuries, spoken English changed so that now |knight| is pronounced /nʌjt/.  The /k/ disappeared, but the |k| didn't, so now there's a mismatch between the spoken and written forms.

---

Sometimes the written and spoken forms of a language evolve separately.  A change in written English might not affect the way words sound, and a change in spoken English might not affect the way words are spelled.  Language always changes over time, whether spoken or written.

I'm glossing over some details in the examples above, but I hope you get the gist of it.

Comment: You say this is very common but I would have thought it's actually pretty unusual. What evidence do you have that it's 'a common phenomenon'?

Comment: Just a quick survey: of the 10 most-spoken languages, 8 of them don't have a 1-to-1 correspondence between sounds and graphemes.  If you'd like, I'd be happy to provide references.

Comment: @Joe Could you tell me which 2 of the 10 do have one-to-one correspondence? Thanks!

Comment: @gonnastop None of those 10 has a perfect one-to-one correspondence (ie a perfectly shallow orthography), but I would have thought that more than 2 would be classified as having shallow orthographies. But re how common deep orthographies are (which is how I interpret the question), my impression is that shallow orthographies are more common across the world's languages. It seems reasonable that the larger languages (which have probably been written for a longer time, and thus seen more language change unaccompanied by orthographic adjustment) would have more irregularities.

Comment: @gonnastop, apparently none of them do.  I'm not familiar enough with Devanagari and related scripts to say one way or the other.

Comment: @GastonÜmlaut, Mark's question is about *any* amount of depth in orthographies.  The opposing situation (a perfectly shallow orthography) isn't very common.

Comment: @Joe But where do you get that assessment from? I doubt that any of the major languages has a perfectly shallow orthography (even Finnish, usually the paradigm example, has some slight irregularities), but I would say that phonemic orthographies would be found in the majority of the languages of Australia, New Guinea (apart from tone) and the Pacific (those that have established orthographies).

Comment: @GastonÜmlaut, my estimate of the "commonness" of this feature is based on the number of people that speak a language with the feature.  There may be thousands of languages with small communities whose orthographies are perfectly regular, but the majority of people speak a language with a non--fully-regular orthography.

Comment: @Joe Ok, that seems to me an odd way to count it (and I accept it may be me that's odd here, not you!), as I would think of each language as an instance of the phenomenon, not each speaker. But fair enough, I'll leave it at that.

Comment: @GastonÜmlaut, I think your way *is* better, particularly for looking at the range of what languages do.  Weighting the data by number of speakers is (I think) better for describing a person's likely experience with other languages, and ... it's easier to make definitive statements about.  We should probably take these kinds of discussions out of the comments, but I'm not stackexchange-savvy enough to know how.

Comment: @Gaston Ümlaut In Russian pronounciation is determined by spelling and spelling mostly (at least for native words) determined by pronounciation. The same I think is in German. The both are quite widespread languages.

Answer (score 0):

There is rarely a one-to-one mapping from sequences of sound to sequences of letters.  The extent to which the same sound will be represented using different spellings will depend on issues such as historical usage (e.g., dialect changes over time), how the word was derived (e.g., whether it was borrowed from another language) and these days the demands of the advertising industry.

The [slike tool](http://www.coding-guidelines.com/slike/) will generate words that sound like a given word and there are various options that let you play around with generating different spellings (you will need to know technical stuff about compiling programming language source code).

Comment: It is rare only in English. -1

Answer (score 0):

Words borrowed from other languages are a big source of rare spellings for existing sounds. If the original spelling and pronunciation are both kept, a new way of spelling might have been introduced. Prior to writing, only the pronunciation could be borrowed so the problem could not occur.

In some languages it is customary to adopt the spelling of borrowings to the spelling of the receiving language, leading to more consistent and easier spelling rules. Another method to maintain a simple system is to change the pronunciation to fit the spelling. Several societies that choose to keep the original spelling seem to have something I had never heard of until about five years ago, spelling bees, that is: competitions to spell rare words!

These days it is common that people learning another language learn to read and write it at the same time, which might lead to knowing how to spell a word but not how to pronounce it, if the spelling system is sufficiently complex.

Comment: In fact, you can even get people who don't speak till a late age, and learn to read on their own at a very early age -- so it becomes unclear whether their native language is written or spoken.

Comment: @Joe Because they don't speak doesn't mean they don't have language. They will have language (in the linguist's sense of the necessary cognitive structures and knowledge), but it's well-known that some children choose not to produce utterances until relatively late.

Comment: @GastonÜmlaut, you're right, and my comment was rather off-base.  It stemmed from confusion about my own native language more than anything else.